# How to read N:M:K relation (databases)?

Tags: database, relational-database, database-schema, cardinality

I understand the N:M, 1:N and N:1 relationships.

Let's suppose we have a travel agency and look at the relation "booking a travel". The entities involved in this relation are customers, employees and the destination. Rules are as follows: one customer can book several travels and a destination can be booked by several customers. Apparently, this relationship is N:M:K.

How do you have to read N:M:K? Is it like 1 customer can book M destinations with N different employees? But you also can't book one same travel with more than one employee, so how do I have to rephrase it, if needed, in several sentences?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

The "base entities" are `customers`, `employees` and `destinations`.

Now consider a single `booking`. It is booked by one and only one customer. It has one and only one destination. It also can be booked with one and only one employee.

Thus there will be 4 tables in the database. The `bookings` table is, using pseudo syntax:

```
BookingId (PK),
CustomerId (FK of [customers]),
EmployeesId (FK of [employees]),
DestinationId (FK of [destinations])
```

Now,

```
SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE CustomerId = xxx
```

will give you the different bookings to various destinations by the same customer, and each booking is made by only one employee. Similarly to bookings by the same employee or to the same destination as well.

Comment: I am asking about how to read the N:M:K notation. More specifically, I ask how to find out that the cardinality is N:M:K given the information I gave above. I ask for how to put the N:M:K relationship into a textual description.

Comment: Well, unfortunately the example you've given is a multiple 1:N relation, it just happens that the side having '1' in the relations are the same entity. It's not a N:M:K relation.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an N:M:K relationship and give a textual description of it (as how to read it)?

Comment: OK sorry the country example is not what you want. How about this: "people have phones and cameras. Each phone model is used by many users. Each camera model is also used by many users. Each user can have more than one phone and more than one camera at the same time".

Comment: So now we'll need 5 tables: `cameras`, `phones`, `users`, `phoneUsers` and `cameraUsers`. It's phones : users : cameras.

Comment: It seems to me that this is rather a N:M relation between Person and Phone and between Person and Camera. Can I just treat it "separately": many phones can belong to one person without mentioning that there might be multiple cameras involved? And then do the same for persons having cameras and leaving apart phones?

Comment: Yup this is it. N:M:K is N:M and a M:K, right? It just happens that the M is shared between the two relations.